# How much to reduce salt when using salted butter in place of unsalted butter

Tags: substitutions, salt, butter

I normally don't keep unsalted butter on hand since I use it so seldom. So when a recipe calls for salt and unsalted butter among its ingredients would it be alright to use salted butter and reduce the amount of salt? And if so, by how much should the salt be reduced? In other words, how much salt is typically contained in a tablespoon, ounce or gram of salted butter?

Comment: I always go the opposite. I keep unsalted all the time and never by unsalted. You can always add salt but it's very difficult to take away.

Comment: unsalted butter doesn't keep long, and if I buy a pound I never manage to use it before it is bad. So I buy salted and try to adjust.

Comment: @KateGregory, I don't think I use a particularly large amount of (unsalted) butter, but I've never had it go bad on me. If you're stocking up, put the extra packages in the freezer, but the opened package should be perfectly fine in the fridge, and we even keep a stick out at room temperature for spreading purposes. It's just too hard to tell how much salt your butter is adding; plus, there are times when you don't want to add any salt at all.

Comment: All types of butter keep nearly forever in the freezer, and it does it no harm. Cut your butter into sizes used for baking etc, and store in a ziploc style bag in the freezer

Comment: What is 5/16 of a teaspoon? How do you, 'eye ball' that? Digital scales are almost cheaper than a set of teaspoons these days.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Depending on brand, it is approximately 1 1/4 tsp per pound (US), or a little more than 1/4 tsp per stick (4 oz).

For most applications, yes it is fine to substitute and adjust; you can just adjust the "salt to taste" step of your recipe in many cases.

There are a very few uses (such as yeast raised dough) where you want to be more precise.  I would not use salted butter for a yeast dough by preference, but if I had to, I would calculate the amount of salt to remove from the other ingredients based on this ratio:

1 1/4 tsp salt / 16 oz butter

Comment: Personally, I think that bread can always use more salt.

Comment: @Sobachatina Maybe, but it will inhibit the rise as so things are a balance :-)

Answer (score 17):

If you're in the US, labeling laws actually make it pretty easy to know exactly how much salt is in your butter, and yes, it varies by brand.

Salt is sodium chloride, it's 40% sodium by weight. Land O Lakes salted butter (my go-to brand) has 90mg of sodium per tablespoon. That means it has 225mg of salt per tablespoon, or 1.8 grams per stick, 7.2 grams per pound. Table salt weighs 5.7 grams per teaspoon, so Land O Lakes salted butter contains 1.26 teaspoon of salt per pound of butter.

I always bake with unsalted butter, but just now I am making a brioche according to a recipe that will take as much as 6 ounces of butter in one loaf. That’s a stick and a half, a BOATLOAD of butter. I wanted to make it special and use a highly rated, European style cultured butter. I’ve got the butter, but it was only available salted. That’s ok. This brand has 55mg sodium per tablespoon. That’s 660mg sodium for all of the butter in the recipe. 660mg sodium = 1650mg salt (NaCl), or 1.65 grams. The recipe calls for 3.3grams  of salt to be added with the (unsalted) butter, so I’ll add (strangely enough) half of that, 1.65 grams.

Answer (score 1):

According to the folks at America's Test Kitchen, the salt content in butter varies and may increase or decrease the amount of water in the butter.   If you use unsalted butter, there are few if any variations.  I've baked muffins and cookies with both salted and unsalted butter and personally prefer unsalted butter in baking but salted butter when adding to a finished dish (vegetables) or making things like grilled cheese.

Comment: America's Test Kitchen/Cook's Illustrated is the *only* source I've seen for the claim about water content varying for salted butter (see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25014/water-content-of-salted-butter), and nutrition facts contradict the claim. So as far as I can tell, it's just the salt that matters, and water is a non-issue here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're substituting the unsalted butter you have into a recipe that calls for salted butter:

- If using metric units, add about 1.5% salt. That means for 100g of butter, add 1.5g of salt.
- If using English measure, add 5/16 tsp per 4 oz stick of butter.

Similarly, if you're substituting salted butter into a recipe that calls for unsalted butter, remove an equivalent amount of salt elsewhere. Be more cautious going this direction, though; for example, if you're making a dish where butter is added separately from the salt, you should think about why the salt is being added separately before using salted butter.

Comment: What is 5/16 of a teaspoon? How do you, 'eye ball' that? Digital scales are almost cheaper than a set of teaspoons these days.