# Can I substitute salted for unsalted butter in chocolate fudge?

Tags: baking, butter

My recipe calls for unsalted butter but I only have salted butter on hand.  Will this be a problem in the taste or consistency of my fudge?

Comment: Does the recipe call for salt to be added?

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/93163/61534

Comment: Including the *entire* recipe would allow us to see whether the increased amount of salt would actually be noticeable.

Answer (score 5):

Provided the butter is not too salty, it should not affect the consistency or setting, but it will add an extra flavour dimension to the fudge. I don't know what ratios you will be using, but salt and sometimes chilli is added to chocolate to add extra flavour. Personally, I would not find a little bit of salt to balance out the sweetness unpleasant, but that would very much depend on the amount in the butter. Too much would be overpowering.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making it at home and in a "small amount" it's okay to use salted butter and will not affect the taste. I often use salted butter at home in my sweet recipes because I think a pinch of salt enhances flavour.