# salted butter or not in a recipe that doesnt have salt

Tags: butter

I have a shortbread recipe that calls for butter, but doesn't say salted or not, just butter. Also it doesn't call for any salt. Which type of butter would be best?

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/93163/61534

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use salted or unsalted butter if the recipe doesn't specify?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/93163/should-i-use-salted-or-unsalted-butter-if-the-recipe-doesnt-specify)

Comment: Welcome to SA!  However, several folks feel like your question is answered by prior questions about salted vs. unsalted butter; see some of the links above.  I'd say that, from the text of your question, you've already answered it.

Comment: but… shortbread **does** have salt in it anyway. That's part of its appeal.